# Trackbar in rqt ros

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, ros, rqt

I am trying to interface ROS and open cv. I was able to threshold the video stream and display the output in rqt. Now  I want to adjust the threshold range by creating a track bar in rqt. How could I implement it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way in terms of integration and looks would be to create your own rqt plugin ([tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials/Create%20your%20new%20rqt%20plugin)). However you'd need to find some way to notify your node about any changes (e.g. via a service call).

Much easier and faster, and usually sufficient, is to re-use existing functionality. In this case, take a look at [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure). This allows you to change parameters on the fly, you only need to define the configuration and register a callback in your code ([tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials)). The GUI integrates into rqt.

Comment: Did you find or create a method to have trackbars in rqt?